# vba macro Date - pone mal la fecha

Tags: excel, vba

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar, estoy con una macro que mete la fecha actual en un arrai, el problema es que cuando ejecuto y meto en una celda la posicion del arrray excel me pone una fecha con el mes invertido. Ejemplo hoy es dia 12/09/2019 pues en vez de ponerme este fecha me pone 09/12/2019.
He probado esto, mifecha = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") meter la fecha en una variable  en el formato que busco y luego meterla en el array, pero cuando ejecuto la macro me vuelbe a girar el dia y el mes... alguna idea?

```
Option Explicit
Dim nombreArray As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim numero As Integer
Dim numfel As Integer
Dim nomcliente As String
Dim clienteDepurado As String


Sub Clientes2()

'#####################
Dim MiFecha As String
Dim mifecha1 As String
Dim mifecha2 As String
MiFecha = Date
'mifecha = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")
mifecha1 = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
mifecha2 = DateAdd("d", 2, Date)

nomcliente = Application.InputBox("Dime un Cliente - Pon solo las 3 primeras letras")

clienteDepurado = Trim(LCase(nomcliente))

Select Case clienteDepurado

    Case Is = "nis"

        Dim niss(0 To 17) As String

        niss(0) = ""
        niss(1) = MiFecha
        niss(2) = ""
 niss(3) = ""
        niss(4) = "24658"
        niss(5) = "NISSAN MOTOR IBERICA"
        niss(6) = ""
        niss(7) = ""
        niss(8) = ""
        niss(9) = "15n"
        niss(10) = mifecha1
        niss(11) = ""
        niss(12) = ""
        niss(13) = ""
        niss(14) = ""
        niss(15) = ""
        niss(16) = "k"
        niss(17) = ""

        Call cogeDatos1(niss)
        End

End Select
End Sub
Sub cogeDatos1(nombreArray)

  For i = 0 To 17 Step 1

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = nombreArray(i)


    Next i

    i = 0

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para las fechas, si quieres poner la fecha entera nunca utilices formatos, utiliza una variable de fecha:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim MiFecha As Date
    Dim MiTiempo As Date
    Dim FechaYHora As Date

    MiFecha = Date
    MiTiempo = Time
    FechaYHora = Now

    Range("A1") = MiFecha
    Range("B1") = MiTiempo
    Range("C1") = FechaYHora

End Sub
```

Si sólo necesitas la fecha, utiliza `Date`, si sólo es la hora `Time` y para ambas `Now`.

Editado para contestar con tu código:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Clientes2()

    '#####################
    Dim MiFecha As Date 'variables tipo fecha
    MiFecha = Date

    Dim nomcliente As String
    nomcliente = Application.InputBox("Dime un Cliente - Pon solo las 3 primeras letras")

    Dim clienteDepurado As String
    clienteDepurado = Trim(LCase(nomcliente))

    Dim niss(0 To 17) As Variant 'si lo declaras como string te fastidiará las fechas, variant puedes poner números, fechas, strings...

    'cuando sólo es una condición no hace falta utilizar el select case, un If te basta.
    If clienteDepurado = "nis" Then
        niss(0) = ""
        niss(1) = MiFecha
        niss(2) = ""
        niss(3) = ""
        niss(4) = "24658"
        niss(5) = "NISSAN MOTOR IBERICA"
        niss(6) = ""
        niss(7) = ""
        niss(8) = ""
        niss(9) = "15n"
        niss(10) = MiFecha + 1 'puedes sumar siempre tiempos cuando manejas variables de fecha 1 = 1 día y 0,... las horas
        niss(11) = ""
        niss(12) = ""
        niss(13) = ""
        niss(14) = ""
        niss(15) = ""
        niss(16) = "k"
        niss(17) = ""
        cogeDatos1 niss 'no necesitas utilizar el Call para llamar a otra función.
    End If

End Sub
Sub cogeDatos1(nombreArray As Variant)

    Dim i As Long, Fila As Long, ColumnaInicial As Long        

    ColumnaInicial = 1 'la columna en la que empezarás a pegar los datos

    'utilizar  .ActiveCell o .ActiveWorkbook igual que utilizar .Select o .Activate puede dar lugar a muchos errores
    'visita este post para aprender a no utilizarlos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MiHoja") 'cambia MiHoja por el nombre de la hoja
        Fila = .ActiveCell.Row 'la fila en la que quieres pegar los datos            
        For i = 0 To 17 Step 1
            .Cells(Fila, i + ColumnaInicial) = nombreArray(i)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Verás que te he cambiado bastantes cosas, te he dejado escrito la mayoría de cambios con comentarios y algunos consejos. Las variables globales son muy peliagudas porque cualquier función te las puede cambiar y puedes perder el hilo de dónde. Es mejor no utilizarlas, pasar variables a otras macros/funciones como has hecho en este caso sería lo ideal.

Por último, nunca utilices la variable `Integer` es un `Long` truncado, ocupan lo mismo y excel incluso necesita hacer algo extra, utiliza siempre `Long`.

Editado2:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Hola Damian, gracias por tu rapida respuesta, primeramente utilizaba directamente a Date sin meterlo en una variable pero como te digo me invierte la fecha, ahora he probado de meterlo en una variable como dices tu y nuevamente me invierte la fecha, me pone el dia por el mes y el mes por el dia, EL resultado que muestra para el dia de hoy es 9/12/2019 cuando quiero 12/09/2019

Comment: Es que excel se comporta muy mal con las fechas directamente, hay que meterlas en variables porque por defecto tira al formato americando `mmddaaaa`. Al meterlo en una variable ya te lo pone con formato local... Yo siempre trabajo así las fechas para evitarme sustos con cambiarme mes y día.

Comment: @Carlos pon el código que tienes por favor, es algo de formatos 100% pero necesitaría ver dónde tienes el fallo. Si pruebas mi macro verás que pone bien la fecha y no altera mes/día.

Comment: ahora si ya he elimado el parte 2 y dejado este con el código

Comment: @Carlos a ver si así te sirve!

Comment: Hola Damian, gracias por la ayuda pero lo he escrito tal cual lo tienes y me sigue saliendo la fecha invertida, es mas ahora me esta invirtiendo el parametro fecha +1 en la posicion del array 10 que antes curiosamente este dato me lo ponia bien XDDD que locura, voy a repasarlo otra vez algo tengo que haber puesto mal

Comment: @Carlos acabo de testearlo y me pone todo correcto... he adjuntado una captura del resultado.

Comment: hola damian, una cosa, a parte de que le tengo que encontrar el fallo, yo quiero que mi fila sea la celda activa, pero esto no funciona, Fila = ActiveCell.Select , como lo harias tu?

Comment: No hay otra manera de encontrar esa celda activa? es la primera fila sin datos?

Comment: Es que no es la primera fila, es la celda de la primera fila en la que yo situe el cursor, entonces no me vale que me escriba en cells fila 1

Comment: @Carlos pero entiendo que sigues una lógica para seleccionar esa celda... Imagino que debe de ser una base de datos y quieres ir añadiendo filas, ergo necesitas que sea la primera fila sin datos, sea la fila 2 o la 2335, no?

Comment: exectamente, pues tengo unas cabeceras y bajo estas cabeceras los datos, a veces donde quiero introducir un cliente es el la fila a20 como puede ser la a30

Comment: hepuesto una imagen, como ves en cualquiera de los espacios vacios podria colocar datos

Comment: Ok, no me gusta usar `ActiveCell` pero en tu caso es lo más simple. Ya te he editado la respuesta @Carlos

Comment: Gracias!! ahora funciona bien!